# Is there a way to manually set DX and DY when moving anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

I'm a Software Engineer willing to learn more about design stuff. I've been trying to create a logo for a project and I am stuck trying to use curved lines. When moving anchors points, I'm having trouble with positioning dX and dY because of my trackpad's lack of precision. Is there a way to manually set dX and dY position in Illustrator?

Picture Example: Can't set dY to 12px.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the point and from the top options bar:

- To set the position just type the *x* or *y* number
- To move it insert <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> the distance to move
  behind the *x* or *y* number

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. So, basically dX and dY actually means the shifting distance from the current X and Y to the new position. In my case, I found that on Illustrator at Transform Panel using default layout from 2017 version.